# java error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I have 3 classes the following configuration:
Class1 has a few methods, some of them abstract:

```
package package1;

public abstract class class1{
    protected abstract void methodX();

    public boolean methodY(){
        //method implementation
    }

    public String thisIsTheMethodThatMatters(){
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

Next, class2 from the same package extends class1, overrides its abstract methods and adds a few other:

```
package package1;

public class class2 extends class1{
    @Override
    protected final void methodX(){
        //method implementation
    }

    public boolean methodZ(){
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

Finally, class3 from a different package extends class2 and overrides a method from class1:

```
package package2;

import package1.class2;

public class class3 extends class2{
    @Override
    public String thisIsTheMethodThatMatters(){
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

I'm using Eclipse, and it doesn't detect any error when coding.
I'm building the project using Maven Build, but building fails saying that thisIsTheMethodThatMatters() **does not override or implement a method from a supertype**
I'm making sure that package1 is built before package2, hence I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: AFAIK, we don't import packages like that, is this the real problematic code? Can you post a MCVE?

Comment: Eclipse compiles all your stuff "in parallel" all your time (unless you disabled "build automatically" in your project options; which ... you shouldn't do). So, normally, even when you are coding, you should see that eclipse gives you red underlines that go away when you put together something "valid". From what you are writing here, things look "OK" ... except for the violations of java coding guides regarding class names.

Comment: I'm building using Maven. I don't know exactly what it means, but it might me relevant.
@Jägermeister, the methods and class names are just an example, not the real ones.

Comment: @Tom, I'm not having any problem there, so it seems like it is compiling.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and refresh the project cache? *"thisIsTheMethodThatMatters() does not override or implement a method from a supertype"* still occurs?

Comment: @Tom, yes, several times...

Comment: Are the classes defined in different maven modules? Or what do you mean with _"I'm making sure that package1 is built before package2"_?

Comment: @Andy, the classes belong to different projects. I'm building all the projects together using Maven Build, and the Console log shows that the project containing classes 1 and 2 is successfully built before the build process fails due to a compilation error in the project containing class3. I've also tried build each project separately, and I get the same behavior.

Comment: If they are different _Maven Modules_, they need to have a common super module (parent) that defines those as submodules to let maven recognize the dependencies between them. If they are completely separate _Maven Projects_ you need to _install_ (!) them before you can use them in the last project. Maybe you also need to force updating snapshot versions.

Comment: @Andy, I can't assure that I'm not making any mistake, but I think I've been doing exactly as you say, and the error persists.

Comment: I tried it on my machine and it works, so it must be something with your configuration! So you did a `mvn install` for the 1st project, then for the 2nd and then for the 3rd, where you get the error? Maybe you could change the maven version for all projects to make sure it gets the newest version? Are you using Java 6 or newer?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen in case you defined your method (thisIsTheMethodThatMatters) in class1 with protected as access modifier. In other words if the method's signature was

```
protected String thisIsTheMethodThatMatters()
```

then you will get the error because the method will NOT be inherited by class3 based on the above scenario

Comment: No, it is defined as public.

Comment: @MarcoCastanho: did you find any solution. I am stuck up same as you, provided I am using Interface, your's is abstract class.